# Don't understand: ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I know this question already exists, but the answers havent helped me.

```
def function(T,theta,A):
   x=(T-theta)/A
   return(x)

filen=pd.read_csv('filename')
filelist=[file,file2,...,filen)
labels=['name1','name2',...]
colors=['red','blue','green',...]
for i in range(len(filelist)):
    x=filelist[i]['column1']
    y=filelist[i]['column2']
    y2=(1/y)
    plt.plot(x, y2, colors[i], label=labels[i])
    plt.legend()
    plt.plot()
    w=np.where(x>170)
    print(x[w])  #error, can only tuple index with multiindex
    other_fit=curve_fit(function,x,y)
    popt, pcov=other_fit
    plt.plot(x, function(x, *popt), colors2[i], label=labels2[i])
    plt.show()
```

The error occurs at `x[w]`.
When I am not in the for loop, there is no error.

> The error message is as follows:
>
> ```
> ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
> ```

Comment: Please include a complete error message in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change:

```
w=np.where(x>170)
```

to:

```
w = x[x>170]
```

`np.where` returns a tuple in your case:

> ### Returns
>
> ```
> If only `condition` is given, return the tuple
> ``condition.nonzero()``, the indices where `condition` is True.
> ```